# Problems when setting a integer-value by PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in my hazelcastconfig

Tags: spring, properties, hazelcast

I am using spring with hazelcast and the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer of spring for inserting properties into the spring-xml which change by different environment.

e.g.:

```
hz:network port="${hazelcast.port}" port-auto-increment="true"
```

i'd like to change the max-idle-seconds of a map (should be different for every environment). But this won't work because it doesn't recognize it as an integer:

```
hz:map name="default" backup-count="2" max-size="0"
max-idle-seconds="${hazelcast.maxidleseconds}" />
```

I get this exception when i try to run it:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${hazelcast.maxidleseconds}' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
```

Maybe it's not possible for the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to insert an integer. Maybe it's a problem related to the hazelcast.xsd.

Maybe somebody here know a solution?

tia && regards
  noircc

Comment: What version of Spring an Hazelcast are You using?

Comment: Hey, I solved it. Had the version 1.9.4, updated the whole stuff to 2.0.2 ,(solution:http://groups.google.com/group/hazelcast/browse_thread/thread/73d8994234bc9a48). Anyways thx for caring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Edit**: *Although solution is provided in Hazelcast group, I am posting here for visibility.*

This is an old issue that was fixed a while ago. Upgrade to 2.x versions and update xml configuration header to:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-2.0.xsd">
```

Also please look at [Hazelcast-Spring integration](http://hazelcast.com/docs/2.0/manual/single_html/#SpringIntegration) documentation for details.

Comment: Again: Thanx for all your help! I would upvote if i got 15 points.